# Enable one component do display data from two api fetches

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For a react application, I'm using Redux to fetch data from an API. In this application, there exists a component that is displayed twice on the same page. The component is connected to an action and reducer.

Both instances of the component should display different data: one displays someone's job and the other displays someone's phone number. Both of these things are requested in separate API calls, causing the problem that the data of the second call, overwrites the data obtained in the first call in the reducer connected to the component. How would it be possible to make two API calls for such a component that is shown twice, such that both instances of it show the data of either one of these api calls?

I tried the following: make one request and fill the reducer. Then make the other request and merge the results of both in the reducer. However, the problem with this approach is that it is also possible to display only one of the components in the application.

This is the react component:

```
class Display extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { fetchpayload } = this.props;
    fetchpayload(this.props.parameter);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <h1>{this.props.payload}</h1>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  payload: state.DisplayReducer.payload,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators(
  {
    fetchpayload: payloadAction,
  },
  dispatch,
);
```

This is the reducer

```
const initialState = {
  payload: [],
};

export function DisplayReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCHED_DISPLAY':
      return {
        ...state,
        payload: action.payload,
      };
      return state;
  }
}
```

The action file makes the request, and dispatches 'FETCHED_DISPLAY'.

Comment: This problem is all about implementation so please provide some code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added the component and the reducer. Let me know if more is needed!

Comment: Do you have to use "payload" as the key? Can't you just create two fields: "job" and "phone number"? I assume that you pass the data type in "this.props.parameter" so you can just use it to display the value later

Comment: Unfortunately not, because after the second fetch request will then overwrite the first one, causing job to be undefined (as the second request then didnt include a job).

Comment: If you pass the parameter to the action and then based on that set only the field in the state that you need to set everything will be ok

Comment: `causing the problem that the data of the second call, overwrites the data obtained in the first call` who designed your api? If you have a person endpoint like `/person/:id` then why would it ever return something other than a person entity? If you have multiple components dispathing the same fetch action in one render then you can group the action creator (assuming it's a thunk action), how to do that is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62212764/1641941)

Comment: @HMR the endpoint is not exactly the same (the parameters are different depending on the data that needs to be fetched). However, one action is used for both requests.

Comment: I guess you should talk to the endpoint designer about REST and entitities. You can't return a different entity when parameters change so `/people` will always return persons and `people/:id` will return a person. Maybe `people/:id/jobs` can return jobs but that is a different entity and probably can be fetched by `/jobs/?personId=` so should not be overwriting people in your state. What concerns me is that you have 2 entities for person, one with phone number and one with job. That looks like an api REST design begging for failure.

Answer (score 0):

just don't override your stuff inside reducer

```
const InitialState = {
  person: {
    name: '',
    job: ''
  }
};

export default (state = InitialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case NAME:
      return {
        ...state.person,
        person: {
          job: ...state.person.job,
          name: action.payload
        }
      }
    case JOB:
      return {
        ...state.person,
        person: {
          name: ...state.person.name,
          job: action.payload
        }
      }
 // do that with whatever property of object person you would want to update/fetch
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But besides this, I agree with HMR. Why are you fetching twice the same entity for different properties at all?